# Change Android Studio 1.5 Interface Color

Tags: android, android-studio, themes, preferences, appearance

I changed my color scheme from Default to Dracula, and along with the syntax colouring, the Android Studio interface was set to dark as well.

However, now if I select the Default theme again, the *interface* remains dark, and would not change back to light grey/white as it should.

I read that in other version's of Android Studio you could change the interface color from `Preferences > Editor > General > Appearance`, but I cannot find any theme-related settings there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the theme (interface) option, in OSX is actually under `Preferences > Appearance & Behaviour > Appearance`.

It is not that straightforward considering the syntax colouring options are in another section entirely :/

Answer (score 1):

From your Keyboard press Ctrl+` (back quote) a popup will show

change whatever you want to change from there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you go to: Settings > Appearances > Theme

From there in the theme window, did you see a Theme drop down options? If so try changing it there.

If you've already tried this. Try restarting your Android Studio, if it doesn't make a difference, try changing it again as the change may not have saved before.